# MySQL prepared statement significantly slower than query

Tags: sql, mysql, prepared-statement

I'm having a weird situation where running any prepared statement on an AWS RDS MySQL 8.0 instance is significantly (> 100x) slower than running the exact same query manually.

For instance

```
PREPARE stmt1 FROM "select * from customers";
EXECUTE stmt1;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt1;
```

is much slower than

```
select * from customers;
```

In this case they are both fast, but with a query that runs for ~10 seconds as a query, the same prepared statement easily runs over an hour.

In fact I can `SHOW PROCESSLIST`, copy the SQL for a slow prepared statement, run it as a query, get results, go back to the process list and still see the prepared statement running.

This is true for any prepared statement, regardless of the number of variables, regardless of the client used.

Any ideas what might be causing this strange behaviour?

Comment: @Martjin       Please review this URL content. - https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-prepared-statement.aspx -  You may need to use single quote rather than " around your statement.  Get the prepared done.  Then Execute, Then Deallocate the statement name.

Comment: Please post similar information about your query that takes ~ 10 seconds and the code used to prepare, execute and deallocate.

Comment: Most people do not PREPARE, EXECUTE and DEALLOCATE in a single process id.

Comment: Turns out that the prepared statement was hitting a completely wrong index for a small part of the query, causing it to boom from running about 10 seconds to running for well over 60,000 seconds. I knew that prepared statements could calculate different execution plans, but not to this extent. Fixed it by using an index hint.

Comment: Congratulations and THANKS for your solution of using an index hint.  
Did you use "FORCE INDEX" in the query you PREPARED?

Comment: I ended up using "USE INDEX" in the prepared statement.

Comment: Also, keep in mind if you use a prepared statement that is several days/weeks old, the index chosen by the optimizer on the DATE PREPARED will stay in place until another PREPARE is completed.  Growth in cardinality would be ignored as well.